# How to automatically open (on load) & close below modal dialog after a minute

Tags: modal-dialog

I am using the bootstrap modal in one of my projects.

This should open page onload and if the user doesn't close the bootstrap modal for a minute. Then its automatically needs to close the bootstrap modal.

How to set the timer for closing the bootstrap modal automatically?

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg theme-modal" id="overlay" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content quick-view-modal">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                </button>
                <p>
                    Context here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```